# strange result of "!TRUE + TRUE" in r

Tags: r

I met a very stange problem. The statement is like this:

```
!TRUE + TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

the result is FALSE, not the number 1.
But when I add a () to !TRUE:

```
(!TRUE) + TRUE
[1] 1
```

the result is what I expected.
Here is what I consider about the statement "!TRUE + TRUE".

It seems like the TRUE was coerced to a numeric 1, and caculate the 1 + 1 to 2, and then the number 2 was coerced to a logical value TRUE, and finally !2 equals to FALSE.
In this case, the operator precedence of "!" is not the first.

So how does R run this kind of statement, I don't find the reason in R source code. Dose there exist any similar example?

Comment: Just because you wrote it `!TRUE + TRUE` without any space between `!` and the expression that follows, doesn't mean that's the operator precedence the interpreter uses. `! (TRUE + TRUE)` would make it obvious what's happening.

Comment: I expect the of result of statement "!TRUE + TRUE" is same as "(!TRUE) + TRUE", but it is not. I dont think it is the problem of space.

Comment: See ?Syntax for operator precedence. Then you can check your expectations :-)

Comment: Paul: I know it's not space, it's R operator precedence, specifically in R `!` is unnaturally low, lower than `+`. Compare to [in C `!` has the second-highest precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), and other languages. I was pointing out to you that when you drop the space in `!TRUE ...` you can visually fool yourself into thinking you're telling the R interpreter what the precedence should be, but you're not, it ignores that.

Comment: thanks smci, I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple result of operator precedence, see `?Syntax`:

```
:: :::  access variables in a namespace
$ @ component / slot extraction
[ [[    indexing
^   exponentiation (right to left)
- + unary minus and plus
:   sequence operator
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%)
* / multiply, divide
+ - (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
!   negation
& &&    and
| ||    or
~   as in formulae
-> ->>  rightwards assignment
<- <<-  assignment (right to left)
=   assignment (right to left)
?   help (unary and binary)
```

i.e., `+` is evaluated before `!`, therefore your expression is evaluated like

```
!(TRUE + TRUE)
```

i.e., `FALSE`

Another way to see this: look at the AST. A cheap way to get an idea of this is:

```
as.list(substitute(!TRUE + TRUE))
# [[1]]
# `!`

# [[2]]
# TRUE + TRUE
```

i.e., `!` is the outermoust call, and `TRUE+TRUE` is done first.

A more advanced way to approach this is to use the `lobstr` package which has a function for nicer visualization of the AST:

```
lobstr::ast(!TRUE + TRUE)
# █─`!` 
# └─█─`+` 
#   ├─TRUE 
#   └─TRUE
```